# Webrtc no video when users are on different network

Tags: google-chrome, signalr, webrtc

So I have a website set up. With a clienta page and a clientb page.

This is basically a split version of this site:
https://webrtc-demos.appspot.com/html/pc2.html

I am using signalr (websockets) to exchange information between the clients.

**When a user opens up both cleinta and b on the same computer it works fine.**

**When a user opens up clienta on one computer and on another computer opens up clientb BUT both computers are on the same network, it works fine.**

**When a user open up clienta on one computer and on another computer opens clientb BUT on different networks there is no video or audio.**

When the ice messages are exchanged i pass back a number so i know the order its sent. On the opposite end they dont always arrive the same order, but audio #1 always gets there before audio#2. and the same with video.

In all cases im using chrome dev 24.

I realize sequence and timing are everything with webrtc. Im just not understanding how it can work on separate pcs on the same network but not different networks. I should point out that when i say same network ive test both at work with 2 pcs and at home with 2 pcs. so i dont think its a firewall thing.

Any ideas?

I did check out https://apprtc.appspot.com/ as its a slightly more relevant link. This lead me to adding a couple settimeouts though they didnt seem to help.

One last thing, i did mention about the ice messages. I should also note that both sides send and receive all the messages. an offer is created and an answer is created. Hence, it working on same network machines.

**Update:**

Im using jsep and all the latest syntax according to webrtc.org

**Update 11/15/2012:**

So is there a open source package for creating a media relay?

Specifically .net, but could be php. The current site is public facing, this is how I was able to test on multiple networks. So it seems like I just need another endpoint for the media relay.

**Updated 11/16/2012:**

In hopes that I'll get it working or get valuable input from other developers I'm putting my code out on github.

https://github.com/thorst/RTC

**Updated 11/21/2012**

The code now works for everything except different network connections. (as described in this post)

**Updated 5/28/2013**

This years google io was much better at explaining turn, stun, and ice.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=p2HzZkd2A40

For reference here are the older helped me get started

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8C8ouiXHHk

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAhhniqwkp8

Answer (score 3):

Chrome doesn't implement TURN yet. STUN will only help with some types of NATs but not with symmetric ones which are prevalent in home routers. You need a media relay with a public IP to connect two devices that are behind symmetric NATs and the standard for that is TURN https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766 .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I'm assuming by your answer that TURN **will** be implemented by chrome at some point in the future?